# Adding Title to Elementor Pro Media Carousel Widget

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, elementor

I'm missing the option to add a title to each slide of the Elementor Pro Media Carousel Widget. I'm using the description of images within the overlay option, but I also need to have a title of each slide shown underneath within the carousel. A text input field each slide would be best, but if there's away to append the media's title with some script would be a way also. Does anyone have a solution for this? The image carousel has that option. I don't know why it's not included within the media carousel widget though..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can display the caption or title in the Overlay.  And using CSS give the overlay transparent background and opacity=1 so the text is always visible.  Something like this:

```
.elementor-carousel-image-overlay.e-overlay-animation-fade {
background-color: transparent;
bottom: 0px !important;
align-items: flex-end;
opacity: 1 !important;
font-weight: 500;
padding: 0;
padding-bottom: 3%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add another field to an existing widget, the best approach is to do it by editing the widget code and add a new field.

Alternatively, you can look for another Media Carousel Widget that might have those fields already. Jet Elements has one: https://crocoblock.com/plugins/jetelements/ but there are probably others.

EDIT: If neither of those is an option, you can look at https://wordpress.org/plugins/unlimited-elements-for-elementor/. It might work for what you need.

Comment: Thanks again for the recommondations. I like the crocoblock plugins. For this one I really want to avoid a truckload of code with another huge widget library plugin. I'm trying to override or extend the Media Carousel Widget with a simple custom plugin if possible..

Comment: I find that this posts helps when creating a plugin to add Elementor Widgets. https://benmarshall.me/build-custom-elementor-widgets/. You then have to add the new custom version of the Widget to the plugin that you created

Comment: That's the exact tutorial I'm using as a starter right now :)